# Is there a foreign exchange/currency limit when leaving India?

Tags: india, money, exchange

I am an Overseas Citizen of India (OCI); I'm leaving India and have some spare cash in Rupees. I would like to covert Rupees to USD for travel expenses.

Is there a limit on USD cash or travellers cheques that can be taken out of India, when an OCI is departing India?

Is there an organisation that offers foreign exchange services to an OCI?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Reserve Bank of India](https://m.rbi.org.in//SCRIPTS/FAQView.aspx?Id=66#q3)

> **Q 3. How much foreign currency can be carried in cash for travel abroad?**
>
> Ans. Travellers going to all countries other than (a) and (b) below
>   are allowed to purchase foreign currency notes / coins only up to USD
>   3000 per visit. Balance amount can be carried in the form of store
>   value cards, travellers cheque or banker’s draft. Exceptions to this
>   are (a) travellers proceeding to Iraq and Libya who can draw foreign
>   exchange in the form of foreign currency notes and coins not exceeding
>   USD 5000 or its equivalent per visit; (b) travellers proceeding to the
>   Islamic Republic of Iran, Russian Federation and other Republics of
>   Commonwealth of Independent States who can draw entire foreign
>   exchange (up-to USD 250,000) in the form of foreign currency notes or
>   coins. For travellers proceeding for Haj/ Umrah pilgrimage, full
>   amount of entitlement (USD 250,000) in cash or up to the cash limit as
>   specified by the Haj Committee of India, may be released by the ADs
>   and FFMCs.

Comment: Is the outward cash limit set by RBI (Q3) applicable to a foreign citizen holding OCI card?

Comment: There is no indication it does not apply to an OCI.